# Adding pointers

Tags: delphi, pointers, buffer

```
var Buffer: TMemoryStream
```

*The code:*

```
Move((PByte(Buffer.Memory)+Buffer.Position)^, Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size - Buffer.Position);
```

Unfortunately this is not possible: *Operator is not applicable to this type of operand.*

**So how can I get the starting point of a MemoryBuffer?**

Comment: What's the definition of Buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only add/subtract integer from a character pointer. From Delphi help:

> You can use the + and - operators to
>   increment and decrement the offset of
>   a character pointer. You can also use
>   - to calculate the difference between the offsets of two character pointers.
>   The following rules apply.
>
> If I is an integer and P is a
>   character pointer, then P + I adds I
>   to the address given by P; that is, it
>   returns a pointer to the address I
>   characters after P. (The expression I
>   + P is equivalent to P + I.) P - I subtracts I from the address given by
>   P; that is, it returns a pointer to
>   the address I characters before P.
>   This is true for PChar pointers; for
>   PWideChar pointers P + I adds
>   SizeOf(WideChar) to P.
>
> If P and Q are both character
>   pointers, then P - Q computes the
>   difference between the address given
>   by P (the higher address) and the
>   address given by Q (the lower
>   address); that is, it returns an
>   integer denoting the number of
>   characters between P and Q. P + Q is
>   not defined.

Try this:

```
Move((PAnsiChar(Buffer.Memory)+Buffer.Position)^, Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size - Buffer.Position);
```

Comment: Use PAnsiChar, not PChar, lest your code suddenly get weird errors next time you upgrade Delphi.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I have edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that original code with PByte should work in Delphi 2009, as it now has more types with pointer math enabled.

Comment: True, but you need to add {$pointermath on} to enable that afaik.

Comment: No, you don't.
You can use pointermath to enable pointer math on new type or on block of code. Build-in PByte type already have pointer math enabled, so you don't need any additional directives.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting Buffer.Memory to PByte and want to add an Int64 value. That doesn't work (Delphi is very strict about what you do with pointers). Try this:

```
Move(Pointer(Int64(Buffer.Memory)+Buffer.Position)^, Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size - Buffer.Position);
```

This works to:

```
Move(PAnsiChar(Buffer.Memory)[Buffer.Position], Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size - Buffer.Position);
```

This "should" work in Delphi 2009 with pointermath on:

```
Move(PByte(Buffer.Memory)[Buffer.Position], Buffer.Memory^, Buffer.Size - Buffer.Position);
```

Comment: The latter example would only work if `Memory`'s type were `PByte`. Isn't it still `Pointer`?

Comment: I added an cast to PByte, but isn't it possible to just use Pointer?